# Regex to match 8 char length with some set letters required

Tags: regex

I am working on a Regular expression to construct a:

8 character string
Must contain at least 1 m,d,(another m), i, l

The remaining 3 letters should be wildcard [a-z]

The required letters can be in any order.

Thank you!

Edit: Examples: mdmilaaa, madmilaa, ladmiamb, umlaimdy (can provide more if needed)

Edit: 
The final 8 char string must contain 2 m's. if the wildcards where all at the end of the 8 chars it would be easy with: mdmil[a-z]{3}.. but I am looking for the required letters to be allowed to be scattered throughout. The wildcards can be repeats of the required letters (ie the final string can contain 3 m's or 2 d's)

Edit:
It also looks like the tool I want to use does not allow for the assert construct (?=). If possible to do it without it that would be great. Otherwise the answer is given.

Comment: Could you give some examples of valid and invalid strings?

Comment: I think this would be easier without a pure Reger solution

Comment: Agreed with @Gary. You want to generate a string, and the i'th character depends on whether or not the character sequence from 0 to i-1 already satisfies certain conditions.

Comment: Must the required chars all be in the first 5 chars?

Comment: @Gary I am using a script that generates a list of all possible outputs for a given regex. I need to get a full list (multiple thousands) with this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
(?=.*m.*m)(?=.*d)(?=.*i)(?=.*l)[a-z]{8}
```

Comment: That seems to do it! Thanks. Now to get it to work with my regex generation script. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to redo this regex without the assert regex construct? The tool I am using to generate all possible permutations does not allow for assert (?=). Thoughts?

Comment: Fair enough. My own limitations. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, positive look-ahead can help you:

```
^(?=.*m{1,})(?=.*[a-z]+).{8}$
```

Assuming, you are dealing with case-insensitive characters.

Check out the [online demo](http://rubular.com/r/OoTH3tO6dv).